# Simple Error: Express 3 -> 4. Moving a controller and requesting index "Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]"

Tags: node.js, express, controller, express-4

Hi I've seen similar errors, but none of them apply to this circumstance.  I'm working through the Getting Mean book but applying all the lessons on Express 3 to an Express 4 app.

In app.js

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app_server/views'));
//index.jade is located here and confirmed to work before moving controller
...
require('./routes')(app); 
//Instead of app.use('/', routes);
```

In routes/index.js

```
var ctrl = require('../app_server/controllers/main');

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.get('/', ctrl.index);
};
```

In app_server/controllers/main.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Loc8r' });
});

// /* Also tried */
// exports.index = function(req, res){
//  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
// };
```

Running the app yields "Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]" on the res.render('index', { title: 'Loc8r' }); line.

Been at this for hours.  Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is likely caused by this line in `route/index.js`:

```
app.get('/', ctrl.index);
```

While `app_server/controllers/main.js` now makes use of `express.Router`, `route/index.js` hasn't been updated to match. It's still expecting a `ctrl.index`, which is no longer being defined.

```
console.log(ctrl);       // {}
console.log(ctrl.index); // undefined
```

---

`app_server/controllers/main.js` should export the `Router` it's defining:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = module.exports = express.Router();
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

// ...
```

So it can be used as middleware in `routes/index.js`:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(require('../app_server/controllers/main'));
};
```

---

[Edit] Regarding my comment below:

```
/** app_server/controllers/main.js **/
var express = require('express');
var router = module.exports = express.Router();

// ...
```

```
/** routes/index.js **/
var express = require('express');
var router = module.exports = express.Router();

router.use(require('../app_server/controllers/main.js'));
// ...
// router.use('/area1', require('../app_server/controllers/area1.js'));
// router.use('/area2', require('../app_server/controllers/area2.js'));
```

```
/** app.js **/
// ...

app.use(require('./routes'));
```

Comment: Thank you this worked!  It says I can't up-vote because I need 15 rep... :\

Comment: I am curious why I can't define app=require('express') in index.js instead of having to pass it via require('./routes')(app);

Comment: @boblikesoup `require('express')` will only give you the `express()` constructor for an Application rather than the `app` instance you've created. It's possible to `require('./app')` to access the instance you've created, but if `app.js` is also requiring the other modules this will create [module cycles](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles). You could also use another `Router` in `routes/index` to collect those from your controllers and `.use()` that in `app.js` as any other middleware.